# Зачем ввели такое понятие как "каретка" в программирование?

Tags: веб-программирование

Это же деталь в старых пишущих машинках...

Comment: В матричных и струйных принтерах тоже есть каретка.

Comment: Ну так программирование появилось в те времена, когда мониторов не было, а вывод информации происходил на текстовые принтеры.

Comment: Да и при работе на мониторе с тактом визуально происходит то же, что происходило на печатных машинках. Новый термин для этого решили не придумывать

Comment: Потому и ввели, что первые программы работали именно с пишущими машинками (принтерами)

Comment: (а по-моему вопрос зря закрыли, он вроде имеет право на существование, только тег [терминология] дописать бы ещё)

Answer (score 2):

Потому что первые терминалы были практически идентичны пишущим машинкам. Отличие было только в том, что вместо листов бумаги там был бумажный рулон. Так что была там каретка, и возврат каретки соответственно.

---

Дополнение:
Вот [здесь](https://yandex.ru/images/search?text=%2BConsul%20260%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BF&stype=image&lr=2&source=wiz) можно посмотреть картинки, и даже нашлось [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qjeGmehXfRc).